# Cannot read properties of null (reading 'value') at Item.lerDados, at Item.inserir, at HTMLButtonElement.onclick

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

So i've been trying to reproduce a project for a couple of days, but now im with this problem of the not recognizing(?) the value. Whats possibly causing this error to happen? also if you guys notice any incoherence in my code attempt,or have any suggestion, fell free to also point out.

HTML:

```
<body>
    
    <h1>Cadastros de produtos</h1>
    
    <div class="dias">

        Escolha o dia da semana desejado:

        <select id="dias-semana">

            <option value="dia1" selected>Segunda</option>
            <option value="dia2">Terça</option>
            <option value="dia3">Quarta</option>
            <option value="dia4">Quinta</option>
            <option value="dia5">Sexta</option>
            <option value="dia6">Sábado</option>
            <option value="dia7">Domingo</option>

        </select>

    </div>

    <div class="item"> 

        Escolha o item desejado:
        
        <input type="text" placeholder=""> 
    
    </div>

    <div class="botao-centro"> 
        
        <button onclick="item.inserir()">Inserir dados</button> 
    
    </div> 

    <div id="saida">

        <table border="1" width="100%" height="5%">

            <thead>

                <th>Segunda</th>
                <th>Terça</th>
                <th>Quarta</th>
                <th>Quinta</th>
                <th>Sexta</th>
                <th>Sábado</th>
                <th>Domingo</th>
                <th>Ações</th>

            </thead>

            <tbody id="tbody">
            <tr>
                <td>1</td>
                <td>2</td>
                <td>3</td>
                <td>4</td>
                <td>5</td>
                <td>6</td>
                <td>7</td>
                <td><img src="edit-icon.png"><img src="remove-icon.png"></td>
             </tr>
            </tbody>
             

        </table>

    </div>

</body>

</html>
```

JavaScript:

```
class Item {

    constructor() {
        this.id = 1;
        this.arrayItems = [];
    }
    
    inserir() {
        let item = this.lerDados();
    
        if(this.validaCampos(item)) {
            this.adicionar(item);
        }
    
        console.log(this.arrayItems);
    }

    adicionar(item) {
        this.arrayItems.push(item);
        this.id++;
    }
    
    lerDados() {
        let item = {}
    
        item.id = this.id;
        item.diasSemana = document.getElementById('dias-semana').value;
        item.nomeItem = document.getElementById('nomeItem').value;
    
        return item;
    }
    
    validaCampos(item) {
        let msg = '';
    
        if(item.nomeItem == '') {
            msg += 'informe o nome do produto';
            }
    
        if(msg != '') {
            alert(msg);
            return false
        }
        
        return true;
    }
    
    }

    let item = new Item();
```

Comment: The error message indicates that the problem is on Line 28, in which you try to read `.value` from this: `document.getElementById('nomeItem')`  However, no such matching element exists in the HTML.

Comment: thanks for you response! I changed it to: item.nomeItem = document.getElementById('item').value; but the error stills persists, any idea of what else could it be?

Comment: just managed to see the absence of the id="item" in the <div class="item">